# Alternatives for setFinishOnTouchOutside for older android device?

Tags: android

I have an activity that using the dialog.theme in the manifest, but I don't want it to be destroyed when the user touches outside of the dialog. I did some search and found setFinishOnTouchOutside(false) to be useful, but it require API11 android 3.0 device. I want my app to be compatible on older android device as well, what is the solution??

Comment: You are lucky man, because on older android devices activity will not be closed on touch outside.

Comment: really?.......But even if this is true, because i need to use setFinishOnTouchOutside(false) for the new android device, the min sdk will still be set to api11, which mean older device still cannot use my app. :(

Comment: check API level and call the function only for API >= 11

Comment: One more question, I have an if statement to check the api level, if yes, then call the function, but there is still a red error says that I have to change the minsdk version, how to solve it??

Comment: I think it is better to Ask new question and post more detailed error. I added complete answer to your question, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are lucky man, because on older android devices activity will not be closed on touch outside.

If you want to call `setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)` for newer devices, check API level before and call the method if API >= 11.

Comment: so this truely worked? im skeptical it will and i dont have a older device to try it.

Comment: @ChuckKelly I've been working with DialogFragments via V4 support library and can tell you, for those at least (I'd be confident for Activities too), that this is indeed the behaviour I'm seeing. Testing on a Nexus One and LG Optimus L3 (both running Gingerbread 2.3.6). Dialogs on both devices stay put when tapping outside their borders.